# How to change font to times new roman when using matlab latex interpreter?

Tags: matlab, plot, latex, matlab-figure

My plot for x axis name using matlab is "normalized time t/T", where "normalized time" should be in times new roman font, the same as normal font as my paper, and t/T should be in math mood. How to do this using matlab latex interpreter?

For example, if I write

```
xlabel('Normalized time $t$', 'Fontsize',10,'Interpreter',"latex");
```

in Matlab, I get

[image]

in the plot, but what I really want to get is

[image]

Comment: https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fontname.html ?

Answer (score 2):

when mixing latex with figure labels, Matlab has [limited font support](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/546197-how-can-i-apply-font-options-when-using-the-latex-interpreter-in-matlab). A hack you can try is use the xlabel without a latex interperter, find its position, and add a text next to it with latex. For example:

```
plot(rand(2))
xlabel('Normalized time', 'Fontsize',20,'FontName',"Impact"); % just text, no latex
% get the xlabel position as [left,bottom,width,height]
a=get(get(gca,'XLabel'),'Extent'); 
text(1.01*(a(1)+a(3)),a(2)+a(4)/2,'$\frac{t}{T}$','Fontsize',20,'Interpreter',"latex")
```

[image]